# Why isn't R showing the legend in ggplot?

Tags: r

I managed to make a nice ggplot with geom_bar but the legend is not showing.
Basically I'm showing the difference between 2 scores for each of my 19 candidates, the candidates are also part of 4 distincts groups (the information is inside my df which is called "GS4Gnew"). 
I manually choose the colors for the bars but I wanted it to be relative of the group. That is specifically what I want to show in the legend (each color for each group).

I assume there is trouble with my code as my aesthetics ar in geom_bar and not in ggplot and I think that's why there is no legend showing... But I have no clue how to resolve it...
Thank you for your help.

```
ggplot(GS4Gnew) +  
  geom_bar(GS4Gnew, mapping=aes(x=Initiales, y=difference4G, colour=Groupe),  
    stat = "identity", 
    fill=c("lightblue","red","red","pink","pink","pink","pink","pink","pink",
          "green","green","green","green","lightblue","lightblue","red","red","red","red"), 
    color="black") +   
  scale_y_continuous(breaks=c(-5,5,15),limits=c(-6,25), expand=c(0,0)) +   
  theme_minimal() +   
  labs(x="Participant",y="Différence entre les deux scores", 
    title = "Modification du score global entre les deux évaluations") +   
  theme(panel.grid.major.x=element_blank(),
    panel.grid.major.y=element_line(colour="darkgrey"),
    plot.title=element_text(size=rel(1.5), face="bold",vjust=1.5),
    axis.title.y=element_text(face="bold",vjust=1.8),
    axis.title.x=element_text(face="bold",vjust=-0.8))
```

Comment: only things inside `aes` are suitable for the legend. You correctly defined color inside  but ouside you overwrite it again with `color="black"` Try to delete the latter one and see what will happen.

Comment: Use `fill = Groupe` inside `aes` and specify the colors with `scale_fill_manual`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to change the `aes` mapping of fill to `fill=Groupe` and give the fill color values inside of `scale_fill_manual`. The code below should work (it's harder to try without an example of your data). If not, try also changing the `fill=Groupe` to `fill=factor(Groupe)` (in case it already isn't a factor).

```
ggplot(GS4Gnew, aes(x = Initiales, y = difference4G, fill = Groupe)) +  
  geom_bar(stat = "identity", colour = "black") +   
  scale_y_continuous(breaks = c(-5,5,15), limits = c(-6,25), expand = c(0,0)) +   
  scale_fill_manual(values=c("lightblue", "red", "red", "pink", "pink", "pink",
                             "pink", "pink", "pink", "green", "green", "green",
                             "green", "lightblue", "lightblue", "red", "red", 
                             "red", "red")) +   
  labs(x = "Participant", y = "Différence entre les deux scores", 
       title = "Modification du score global entre les deux évaluations") +   
  theme_minimal() +
  theme(panel.grid.major.x = element_blank(),
        panel.grid.major.y = element_line(colour="darkgrey"),
        plot.title = element_text(size=rel(1.5), face="bold", vjust=1.5),
        axis.title.y = element_text(face="bold", vjust=1.8),
        axis.title.x = element_text(face="bold", vjust=-0.8))
```

Comment: Thank you very much ! It worked perfectly ! Still some understanding to improve for me !!